# How to cross-reference input with list

Tags: python-3.x, windows, game-development

I'm doing a small little CLI adventure game. And I'm attempting to compare the response a user inputs against a list of actions to make sure its valid but I cant seem to figure out how to do it exactly. Some help would be great!

```
#Preamble/lore goes above here
print("What do you do: ")
response = input()

list = ["inv","Inv","Inventory","inventory","help","Help","Lamp","lamp","Look","look","Search","search","bed","Bed","Use","use","Drink", "drink","Bucket","bucket","Gate","gate","escape","Escape"]

while True:

#Game Code goes above here
        for x in list:
        if x != response:
            scroll(Fore.RED+ "Invalid Input; please enter again.\n"+Fore.WHITE)
            scroll("What do you do: ")
            response = input()
```

I want the game to loop events so users can go back and do actions they may have missed. Say they Searched the area before picking up the map.

Once the user inputs an invalid input; it doesn't allow them to return back to standard inputs say they spelt a keyword incorrectly and attempts to spell it correctly the second time. It'll just keep looping the invalid input message.

I can get it to loop/work correctly when there is no error code for invalid inputs; but if I do that when an invalid input does occur; it'll just crash the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to get it working but in a really unoptimized way. But at least it works. I converted every item from the list into an "and" check not quite sure how or why it works but it does.

```
if response != "inv" and response != "Inv" and response != "Inventory" and response != "inventory" and response != "help" and response != "Help" and response != "Lamp" and response != "lamp" and response != "Look" and response != "look" and response != "Search" and response != "search" and response != "bed" and response != "Bed" and response != "Use" and response != "use" and response != "Drink" and response !=  "drink" and response != "Bucket" and response != "bucket" and response != "Gate" and response != "gate" and response != "escape" and response != "Escape":
        cls()
        scroll(Fore.RED+ "Invalid Input; please enter again.\n"+Fore.WHITE)
        scroll("What do you do: ")
        response = input()
        print(response)
```